# what is the shortest way to write this border css properties?

Tags: html, css, border

i have div called "commentbox"

and i want to have border `solid` color #ccc, but i want the right side, not to bordered.

so only left, top and buttom of the div should be covered with borederlines. thanks

Comment: Here's a good website that teaches CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/css/ You can search for 'borders' or whatever else in the future and there are plenty of examples. Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

probably

```
.commentbox{
  border: solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: cheers thanks that works, sorry for the stupid question hehe, im a newbie to css

Comment: @getaway - we all have to start somewhere :-)

Comment: Actually, the value `0` would have been a tiny bit shorter than `none` for resetting the value :P

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
.commentbox {
border: 2px solid #ccc;
border-right: none; /* though some amend this to: '0 none transparent' */
}
```

Effectively you declare the `width`, `style` and `color` of the border in the shorthand first rule, and then assign a `style` of `none` (although you could use `border-right-width: 0` or `border-right-color: transparent` to achieve the same result in compliant browsers).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
.commentbox{
  border:1px solid color #ccc;
  border-right:none;
}
```

The rule `border:1px solid color #ccc;` will apply border to all four sides but later rule `border-right:none;` will remove it from `right` side leaving you with three sides of the border.

You can read this post on CSS-Trick.Com:

- [Three-Sided Border](http://css-tricks.com/three-sided-border/)